# Extjs: Grid Status bar not updating in one click

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am updating Grid status bar with total number of records after grid uploaded with store
but my status bar is not updating with one click ..it shows me 0 number of records but if i press button second time its gets updated with total number of records, after loading grid store.. updating status bar

```
type: 'statusbar',
 id: 'gridStatusbar'

//for status bar 
            var gridStatusbar= Ext.getCmp('gridStatusbar'); // for status bar 
            var totalCount = grid.getStore().getTotalCount();
            gridStatusbar.setText("Number of records : " + totalCount);
```

can you please help me with this problem

Comment: Do you wait store to finish the load?

Comment: when the store's proxy total property is set, and returned, this is not required.

Comment: no I am not waiting to load store ..do I need to wait ? if yes then how

Comment: getStore.getProxy().setUrl(serviceUrl + '/'+number);
    grid.items.items[0].getStore().load(); Then after this above code come here

Comment: You could also try to use https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.grid.feature.Summary.html instead